# Draw selectable text in rectangle with iText

Tags: java, itext

Shortly, I want to draw a text in specific rectangle using `iText`, which can be selected in PDF editor tool. Here is my try:

```
  Document document = new Document();
  PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE_RESULT));
        document.open();

 // first 
 TextField data = new TextField(writer, new Rectangle(30, 60, 200, 200), "1- this text generated by textfiled");
 data.setFontSize(10);
 data.setTextColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
 data.setText("1- this text generated by textfiled");
 PdfFormField datafield = data.getTextField();
 writer.addAnnotation(datafield);

 // second
 PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();         
 cb.saveState();
 cb.beginText();
 cb.moveText(200, 400);
 cb.setFontAndSize(BaseFont.createFont(), 14);
 cb.showText("2- this text is generated by PdfContentByte ");
 cb.endText();
 cb.restoreState();

 // third
 ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
 writer.setCompressionLevel(0);       
 ct.setSimpleColumn(100,100,400,300);
 ct.setText(new Phrase("3- this text is generated by ColumnText"));
 ct.go();

 document.close();
```

I use `Foxit reader` as PDF tool in my PC and Google drive document on the web, the Google drive can select text but foxit can't (just tested again). 
And [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2RtpAwMIqGTQjc5NGtQUDIxZ3M/edit?pli=1) is the output.

Three ways above aren't what I want. I want another way that I can **input a rectangle (left, top, bottom, right) and the text will fit in this rectangle as it can** (the font size is dynamic). Is there any ideas or example that can achieve this?

P/S: To explain to **Bruno Lowagie**:

- I don't know `PdfContentByte` for adding text is for professionals or not, I just searched and tried it.
- I have already tried the second way (`PdfContentByte`), but it doesn't work then I deleted these codes, so now I have to search again to copy and post into StackOverflow, I think it's similar to my try. Now I write test again.

Comment: You don't mention what you mean by "PDF Editor Tool" and your allegation is wrong. In the first code snippet, you create an AcroForm form field. The text of a text field is interactive. It's selectable, editable and you can copy/paste it. In your second code snippet, you add static text at an absolute position using the most difficult code possible. You probably need `ColumnText`, but you should update your question first as it has different flaws. See http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=59 for `ColumnText` examples.

Comment: I have updated my question. I forgot mention I used `Foxit reader` (and Google Drive on web) to select text, but I think this isn't a reason for voting down and close question request. simply voting down doesn't make any sense. The problem is on the first approach, text can't be select by these tools. Because I'm just a newbie in this library, so I don't know how to do with it correctly, that is the reason why I'm posting here. And I will take a look on `Column Text`. Thanks!

Comment: I "undid" my down vote, but I still think the question is odd. Share the PDF. If you really have an AcroForm text field, it should be selectable, even in Foxit. That's the whole idea of adding an *interactive* field. What you say would be in violation of the ISO standard for PDF. Also, if you're a newbie, you should start with the official documentation. Using `PdfContentByte` for adding text is for professionals. I have no idea why a newbie would copy/paste code like that.

Comment: Moreover, you say you're using iText (JAVA), but in your second code snippet you're using iTextSharp (C#). That kind of makes one doubt what you've tried.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question again. It's my fault because I don't explain exactly what I did and what I want. Could you please take a look?

Comment: Your text field can be selected when opened in Adobe Reader, so the fact that you can't select it in the Google viewer (I doubt that you're using Foxit when you talk about Google Drive) isn't the fault of the PDF, but of the viewer. Finally, your question is still unclear. Nobody understands sentences like "but it doesn't work then I deleted these codes": http://lowagie.com/doesntwork Looking at your PDF, I see that all three methods work (in Adobe Reader).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just looked at your PDF. In essence it contains this content

```
q
BT
200 400 Td
/F1 14 Tf
(2- this text is generated by PdfContentByte ) Tj
ET
Q
BT
1 0 0 1 100 284 Tm
/F1 12 Tf
(3- this text is generated by ColumnText) Tj
ET
```

The font **F1** here is defined as

```
2 0 obj
<</BaseFont/Helvetica/Type/Font/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/Subtype/Type1>>
endobj
```

As you see the **Encoding** is defined as **WinAnsiEncoding**, and I copied from the content stream using just such an encoding.

By simply following the instructions for text extraction in the PDF specification section 9.10 *Extraction of Text Content*, therefore, this is easy to copy. Any PDF reader which cannot copy&paste here, does not even seem to try.

For the text box it is even easier, the field is defined as

```
3 0 obj
<<
  /Ff 0
  /F 4
  /Type/Annot
  /BS<</W 1/S/S>>
  /Subtype/Widget
  /Rect[30 60 200 200]
  /FT/Tx
  /DR<</Font<</Helv 2 0 R>>>>
  /DA(/Helv 10 Tf 0.50196 0.50196 0.50196 rg )
  /T(1- this text generated by textfiled)
  /V(1- this text generated by textfiled)
  /AP<</N 1 0 R>>>>
endobj
```

As you can see, the value is defined just like desired.

Concerning your following question:

> Three ways above aren't what I want. I want another way that I can input a rectangle (left, top, bottom, right) and the text will fit in this rectangle as it can (the font size is dynamic). Is there any ideas or example that can achieve this?

You will essentially have to use the methods you tried, using different font sizes if the result is too large, and restrict yourself  to PDF readers which at least *try* to copy text as described by the specification. I have to admit, though, that I did not consider Foxit to be in the category of readers not trying.

Comment: Thanks very much, only the first way (textfiled) can't be selected by Foxit. I  can only select all the rect form instead of text. Anyway, I think I got this one. But for the text size, the problem is rectangle has dynamic size, I tried to use `BaseFont.getWidthPoint(String text, float fontSize)` to measure width of text until the text can fit rect (put in while loop), but it always larger than rect 's width. Do you have any recommend?

Comment: The text field value also is easily  to extract, even if not using the actual value entry shown above but instead the appearance stream. I'll have a look which method should be used to measure string widths.